# SwiftyJSON returning null

Tags: ios, swifty-json, swift2

I am going to simplify my code example for this. I have this piece of code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoKcc.png

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://blah.com/users").response { (request, response, data, error) -> Void in 

   let json = JSON(data:data!)

   print(json) 
}
```

As you can see in the image, I get the data from the web service, but JSON returns null when trying to initialize it with my data. What am I doing wrong here?

edit: String value returned from  let newStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8hav.png

Comment: Could you transform the data into String using `(data:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding`? and show the value of the string?

Comment: In the screenshot you can see that the data is `html/text` rather than `json/text`

Comment: @Larme yes, now that you've mentioned it..i've tried that and it returns html format. I'm very new to this, sorry if it's a silly question.. but how do I make it right? do i have to somehow specify i need the json/text format?

Comment: Could you update your question with its (the string) value?

Comment: Your link is not for a WebService, and less for a WebService with JSON response. It's like going to a bakery and trying to buy a sausage.

Comment: made it work by adding this to the url.. let URL = NSURL(string: "https://blah.com/users")!
        var mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
        mutableURLRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

Answer (score 0):

I have updated to `Alamofire 2.0` and this syntax works

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters:nil, headers: header)
            .responseJSON { request, response, result in

                switch result {
                case .Success(let data):
                    let json = JSON(data)

                case .Failure(_, let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                }
        }
```